# Where can I find an Objective C code which parses any XML file without knowing before any tag or attribute?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I would like to find a sample of code written in Objective C for iPhone which can parse any XML file, even if we don't know tags or attributes. Does anyone has something like that?

Comment: By definition, any parser can parse a file without knowing the tags or attributes.  Now actually doing something with the data that has been parsed is a different story.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can convert the XML into a NSDictionary which then can be used at your ease.
I have not used this code, but maybe you can try this to convert your xml into dictionary
http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/

Comment: for better performance, libxml is preferred.  probably this can help : http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html